# Google App Script mudando ordem das planilhas do firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, firestore, google-app-engine

Eu achei um script para integrar Firestore com Google Planilhas, mas, ao executá-lo, as colunas ficam de ordem a cada atualização de dados. Como posso resolver isso?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/soDCo.png

Um detalhe: tenho mais colunas que as mostradas no print (só para entenderem)

```
function getFirestore(){
  return FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
}

function importFromFirestore(){
  const firestore = getFirestore();

  const allDocuments = firestore.getDocuments('Visita').map(function(document){
    return document.obj;
  });

  const first = allDocuments[0];
  const columns = Object.keys(first);

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(columns);

  allDocuments.forEach(function(document){
    const row = columns.map(function(columns){
      return document[columns];
    });
    sheet.appendRow(row);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando o seu código acredito que você deva ordenar a array das colunas, isso pode ser feito usando algo como o sort ou o reduce, você pode passar um algoritmo próprio para isso.

Isso ocorre porque quando você solicita uma informação do firestore as "colunas" não vão vir ordenadas, por falar nisso por estar usando o firestore você nem tem garantia que todas as "colunas" vão existir lá.

```js
  //[..]
  const first = allDocuments[0];
  // Ordenar as colunas aqui
  const columns = Object.keys(first).reduce(/*Seu script de redução que retorna uma array ordenada*/);
  // ou
  const columns = Object.keys(first).sort(/*Seu script de ordenacao*/);

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(columns);
  //[..]
```

A ideia apresentada usa o reduce porque ele recebe um valor inicial, uma função que tem como parametros um acumulador e o próximo elemento, dessa forma você pode retornar uma array ordenada da forma como você quer, você também pode passar uma função customizada de sort.

Comment: Ajudou bastante. Deu certo. Muito obrigado.